# validate and number automatic jumping

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I had done a simple interface for validation use.1st you insert the text in "txtinput",if u insert something except words "hello",it will pop out messagebox "please try again".Then at the "txtchance" there number "3" will auto change to "2".Again invalid input,it will chance to "1" and "0" then messagebox show "no more tries" and exit application.

Problem that i face is when i use "for loop" for auto change the "txtchance" number,it will loop all non-stop for me to try again and exit the application.How to stop it or break it?

**here the code**

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public int tries = 2;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        txtchance.Text = "3";
    }

    private void btn_click_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtinput.Text != string.Empty)
        {
            if (txtinput.Text == "hello")
            {
                textBox1_Validated(sender, e);
            }
            else
            {
                textBox1_Validating(sender, e);
            }
        }
    }

    private void textBox1_Validating(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tries > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                txtchance.Text = i.ToString();

                if (i > 0)
                {
                    tries--;
                    txtinput.Clear();
                    MessageBox.Show("Please try again", "Error");
                }

                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Sorry, no more tries", "Error");
                    Application.Exit();
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private void textBox1_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tries != 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Well done, you managed to enter a valid input!", "Validation OK");
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

**Here screenshort**
https://www.imageupload.co.uk/image/Zl1K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for` loop is not needed, at all. What you really want to do is simply check your `tries` field:

```
private void textBox1_Validating(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtchance.Text = tries.ToString();

    if (tries-- > 0)
    {
        txtinput.Clear();
        MessageBox.Show("Please try again", "Error");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Sorry, no more tries", "Error");
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```